# Exclude Empty Form Data in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been working on an integration between two projects, one is written in Java and the other is in Asp.NET MVC.

I realized that when there are two input elements like these in HTML `form` element:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="helloWorld"/>
<input type="hidden" value name="helloWorld"/>
```

Notice there is no value defined for the second one, Asp.NET `Request.Form["helloWorld"]` returns `1,` with a comma, whereas JSP doesn't include that and  returns only `1` and I think this is either a missed issue in Asp.NET or an intentional feature.

Anyways, is there a way to solve this problem? Perhaps, like a configuration in web.config or somewhere, or maybe a small property like `ExcludeEmptyInputs` or something? I was thinking to enumerate each element in `Request.Form` and remove extra `,` from values where it doesn't make sense like above, but I thought perhaps there is an easier and more intuitive way of doing it.

Note: Some of you may suggest removal of the second input but it is not an easy thing to do. So I would like to get answers around my first questions instead.

Comment: Are you binding this to a model? Weird use of two inputs with the same model. Can you rename the inputs? Example: helloWorld1 and helloWord2. Nothing of this is healthy, objects should be uniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NameValueCollection` merges the various values together as a convenience when you use `.Get()` or indexers (`[]`), but under the covers it's representing the values individually. You can use `.GetValues()` to get an array with all the values. Try:

```
string[] values = Request.Form.GetValues("helloWorld");
```

From there you should be able to remove empty values in your own way depending on your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use binders. Not sure in which cases you need substitute array with single variable,
but maybe you can customize binder for your purposes, here is binder for your example

```
public class CustomBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string[] values = request.Form.GetValues("helloWorld");
        if (values != null)
        {
            var notEmptyValues = values.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
            if (notEmptyValues.Count() == 1)
                return notEmptyValues.First();
        }

        return values;
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            /*here is your code*/


            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string), new CustomBinder());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer strong typing binding and a model.
The model...

```
 public class MyModel{

   public string OptionA {get;set;}
   public string OptionB {get;set;}
   public void Post(){
          var userTextA = OptionA;
          var UserTextB = OptionB;
   }
}

public ActionResult MyController(){
    var vm = new MyModel();
    return view(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult MyController(MyModel vm){
   if(modelstate.isValid){

         vm.post();
   }
}
```

And the view

```
@model MyModel
@using(Html.Beginform()){
   @Html.EditorFor(p=>model.OptionA)
   @Html.EditorFor(p=>modle.OptionB)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

This is called strong binding and is fully supported by MVC model binding.  The post method on your model allows you to do something with the selected or edited values.